# Mysqli multi query error

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to execute two or more queries at a time, fetch them one after another.

Then I need to bind param and bind result in each one of them.

I am trying this way but getting error.

```
$query="
SELECT 
`date`, `ip`, AVG(`value`)
FROM `stats`.`stats`    
WHERE `uid`=?
GROUP BY `date`, `ip`;
";

$query.="
SELECT 
`category`, `ip`, AVG(`value`)
FROM `stats`.`stats`    
WHERE `uid`=?
GROUP BY `category`, `ip`;
";

$prepare = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepare, 'ss', $uid,$uid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($prepare) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Then in html part I need to fetch result of these one after another

```
//fetch first query result
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prepare)):
mysqli_stmt_store_result($prepare);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $date,$ip,$value);
mysqli_free_result($result);
endwhile;

//fetch second query result
while (mysqli_next_result($prepare)):
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prepare));
mysqli_stmt_store_result($prepare);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $category,$ip,$value);
mysqli_free_result($result);
endwhile;
```

But its not working showing multiple errors.

```
 Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
 Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
 Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? GROUP BY `date`,`ip` ) ..
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Since bind_param passes by reference you need 2 different variables,even if the values are the same. `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepare, 'ss', $uid,$someotheruid);`

Comment: Those two statements look as though you could just either combine them with `UNION ALL` into one, or modify the `WHERE` clause to be `WHERE uid IN (?,?)`. I don't see a need for multiple queries.

Comment: Your last loop does not have a body to loop over, so it consumes all data, until it returns false on no more data left. That for the warnings.

Comment: Your query is wrong, echo the query, and show us here.

Comment: @frosty query is correct working as separate query.

Comment: @syck it shows error at `mysqli_stmt_execute` doesn't even go further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to execute two or more queries at a time

You don't.

And, therefore, you should use just regular prepare/execute for your queries, running them one by one. A transaction could be added to boost speed and consistency

```
$data = [
    ['col1' => 'foo1', 'col2' => 'bar1'],
    ['col1' => 'foo2', 'col2' => 'bar2'],
];
// prepare SQL query once
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?");

$mysqli->begin_transaction();
// loop over the data array
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $row['col1'], $row['col2']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: then second query shows error and if store result for first error disappears but second query has result of first

Comment: then you should fix the error and shouldn't mix the data for two queries.

Comment: There are no errors in query they are working if one is executed or second without other query, thats why I am going for multi_query

Comment: What's wrong in using multi_query() over multiple prepare()

Comment: Quite everything. You'll do yourself a favor if forget about multi_query()

Comment: will multi_query() be slower than multiple prepare()

Comment: Just. Forget. About. Multi. Query.

Comment: Ok, then can you guide me how to execute second query properly after first, As query are stored in include file and processed in html later. I dont want to make two another include file to include after mysqli close for no errors

Comment: Just run them. there is nothing special in running one query after another. Every php application runs hundreds of them, without a problem. If you get an error then you have to fix it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I found out what I was doing wrong, I was using same names in bind_result variables, now when I changed them they are working one after another, no need for multi_query()